# git rebase with multiple sub-branches

Tags: git, version-control, merge, branch, rebase

I am having trouble getting git to do what I want in moderately complicated branching scenarios.  It seems like some of my work is being lost whenever I use the rebase command. I am new to git, coming from a Perforce background.  Am I using the wrong commands or missing some flags?  Is my intuition about the internal state of my local repository correct?

Note: branchB is dependent on branchA, and branchC is dependent on branchB.

1. git checkout master
2. git pull master
3. git checkout -b branchA

   ```
   ==O master
      \==A branchA
   ```
4. edit branchA
5. git add ...
6. git commit
7. git review
8. git checkout -b branchB

   ```
   ==O==O master
      \==A branchA
          \==B branchB
   ```
9. edit branchB
10. code review requires changes to branchA
11. git add ...
12. git commit
13. git checkout branchA
14. edit branchA
15. git add ...
16. git commit --amend <== should I use --amend here?
17. git review
18. git checkout branchB
19. edit branchB some more
20. git add ...
21. git commit
22. git review
23. git checkout -b branchC

    ```
    ==O==O==O==O master
      \==A branchA
          \==B branchB
              \==C branchC
    ```
24. edit branchC
25. branchA passes code review
26. git add ...
27. git commit
28. git checkout master
29. git pull master
30. git checkout branchA
31. git rebase master branchA
32. resolve merge conflicts
33. git checkout master
34. git merge branchA

    ```
    ==O==O==O==O==A master
       \==B branchB <== is this correct?
           \==C branchC
    ```
35. git checkout branchB
36. git rebase master branchB
37. resolve merge conflicts

    ```
    ==O==O==O==O==A master
          \        \==B branchB
           \==C branchC <== is this correct?
    ```
38. git checkout branchC
39. git rebase branchB branchC
40. resolve merge conflicts <== often redo the same merge conflicts as branchB

    ```
    ==O==O==O==O==A master
                   \==B branchB
                       \==C branchC
    ```
41. design change requires refactoring branchA
42. git checkout master
43. git pull
44. git checkout -b refactorA

    ```
    ==O==O==O==O==A master
                  |==A' refactorA
                  |==B branchB
                      \==C branchC
    ```
45. edit refactorA
46. git add ...
47. git commit
48. git review
49. git checkout branchB
50. git rebase refactorA branchB <== is this a mistake?
51. resolve merge conflicts (three sets of conflicts)

    ```
    ==O==O==O==O==A master
                   \==A' refactorA
                    \  \==B branchB <== is this correct?
                     \==C branchC
    ```
52. git review <== complains about multiple commits
53. git log <== shows that branchB now has a few instances of branchA's commit

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that commits are dependents from the previous one and branches are just pointers to one commit of the commit graph.

Here is the commit graph evolution, numbers are commits, upper are newer, references and branches are aside commits, `HEAD` is your current position.

You can see your evolution of the commit graph by launching `git log --graph --oneline --all --decorate` at each step.

1. git checkout master

   ```
   1 origin/master, HEAD -> master
   |
   0
   ```
2. git pull master

   ```
   1 origin/master, HEAD -> master
   |
   0
   ```
3. git checkout -b branchA

   ```
   1 origin/master, master, HEAD -> branchA
   |
   0
   ```
4. edit branchA
5. git add ...
6. git commit
7. git review

   ```
   2 HEAD -> branchA
   |
   1 origin/master, master
   |
   0
   ```
8. git checkout -b branchB

   ```
   2 branchA, HEAD -> branchB
   |
   1 origin/master, master
   |
   0
   ```
9. edit branchB
10. code review requires changes to branchA
11. git add ...
12. git commit

    ```
    3 HEAD -> branchB
    |
    2 branchA
    |
    1 origin/master, master
    |
    0
    ```
13. git checkout branchA

    ```
    3 branchB
    |
    2 HEAD -> branchA
    |
    1 origin/master, master
    |
    0
    ```
14. edit branchA
15. git add ...
16. git commit --amend => By using `--amend` you create a new commit with the same parent
17. git review

    ```
    3 branchB
    |
    | 2' HEAD -> branchA
    | |
    2 | 
    |/
    1 origin/master, master
    |
    0
    ```
18. git checkout branchB

    ```
    3 HEAD -> branchB
    |
    | 2' branchA
    | |
    2 | 
    |/
    1 origin/master, master
    |
    0
    ```
19. edit branchB some more
20. git add ...
21. git commit
22. git review

    ```
    4 HEAD -> branchB
    |
    3
    |
    | 2' branchA
    | |
    2 | 
    |/
    1 origin/master, master
    |
    0
    ```
23. git checkout -b branchC

    ```
    4 branchB, HEAD -> branchC
    |
    3
    |
    | 2' branchA
    | |
    2 | 
    |/
    1 origin/master, master
    |
    0
    ```
24. edit branchC
25. branchA passes code review
26. git add ...
27. git commit

    ```
    5 HEAD -> branchC
    |
    4 branchB
    |
    3
    |
    | 2' branchA
    | |
    2 | 
    |/
    1 origin/master, master
    |
    0
    ```
28. git checkout master

    ```
    5 branchC
    |
    4 branchB
    |
    3
    |
    | 2' branchA
    | |
    2 | 
    |/
    1 origin/master, HEAD -> master
    |
    0
    ```
29. git pull master

    ```
    5 branchC
    |
    4 branchB
    |
    3
    |
    | 2' branchA
    | |
    2 |
    | |
    | | 6 origin/master, HEAD -> master
    | | |
    |/ /
    | /
    |/
    2
    |
    0
    ```
30. git checkout branchA

    ```
    5 branchC
    |
    4 branchB
    |
    3
    |
    | 2' HEAD -> branchA
    | |
    2 |
    | |
    | | 6 origin/master, master
    | | |
    |/ /
    | /
    |/
    1
    |
    0
    ```
31. git rebase master branchA
32. resolve merge conflicts

    ```
    5 branchC
    |
    4 branchB
    |
    3
    |
    |   2'' HEAD -> branchA
    |   |
    2   |
    |   |
    |   6 origin/master, master
    |   |
    |  /
    | /
    |/
    1
    |
    0
    ```
33. git checkout master

    ```
    5 branchC
    |
    4 branchB
    |
    3
    |
    |   2'' branchA
    |   |
    2   |
    |   |
    |   6 origin/master, HEAD -> master
    |   |
    |  /
    | /
    |/
    1
    |
    0
    ```
34. git merge branchA # the merge is fast-forward

    ```
    5 branchC
    |
    4 branchB
    |
    3
    |
    |   2'' branchA, HEAD -> master
    |   |
    2   |
    |   |
    |   6 origin/master
    |   |
    |  /
    | /
    |/
    1
    |
    0
    ```
35. git checkout branchB

    ```
    5 branchC
    |
    4 HEAD -> branchB
    |
    3
    |
    |   2'' branchA, master
    |   |
    2   |
    |   |
    |   6 origin/master
    |   |
    |  /
    | /
    |/
    1
    |
    0
    ```
36. git rebase master branchB # 2 should be dropped as 2'' is already is the branch
37. resolve merge conflicts

    ```
    5 branchC
    |
    |   4' HEAD -> branchB
    |   |
    4   |
    |   |
    |   3'
    |   |
    3   |
    |   |
    |   2'' branchA, master
    |   |
    2   |
    |   |
    |   6 origin/master
    |   |
    |  /
    | /
    |/
    1
    |
    0
    ```
38. git checkout branchC

    ```
    5 HEAD -> branchC
    |
    |   4' branchB
    |   |
    4   |
    |   |
    |   3'
    |   |
    3   |
    |   |
    |   2'' branchA, master
    |   |
    2   |
    |   |
    |   6 origin/master
    |   |
    |  /
    | /
    |/
    1
    |
    0
    ```
39. git rebase branchB branchC
40. resolve merge conflicts # As the rebase replays all the commits in branchB history that are not in branchC history, it will replay 2, 3, 4 and 5; that why, if you had conflicts, you may encounter them again

    ```
        5' HEAD -> branchC
        |
        4' branchB
        |
        3'
        |
        2'' branchA, master
        |
        6 origin/master
        |
       /
      /
     /
    1
    |
    0
    ```
41. design change requires refactoring branchA
42. git checkout master
43. git pull
44. git checkout -b refactorA

    ```
    5' branchC
    |
    4' branchB
    |
    3'
    |
    2'' branchA, master, HEAD -> refactorA
    |
    6 origin/master
    |
    1
    |
    0
    ```
45. edit refactorA
46. git add ...
47. git commit
48. git review

    ```
    5' branchC
    |
    4' branchB
    |
    |  7 HEAD -> refactorA
    |  |
    3' |
    | /
    2'' branchA, master
    |
    6 origin/master
    |
    1
    |
    0
    ```
49. git checkout branchB

    ```
    5' branchC
    |
    4' HEAD -> branchB
    |
    |  7 refactorA
    |  |
    3' |
    | /
    2'' branchA, master
    |
    6 origin/master
    |
    1
    |
    0
    ```
50. git rebase refactorA branchB <== is this a mistake?
51. resolve merge conflicts (three sets of conflicts)

    ```
    5' branchC
    |
    |  4'' HEAD -> branchB
    |  |
    4' |
    |  |
    |  7 refactorA
    |  |
    3' |
    | /
    2'' branchA, master
    |
    6 origin/master
    |
    1
    |
    0
    ```
52. git review
53. git log # As you rebased your branch branchB on top of refactorA which is created from master who merged branchA, branchA commits are in branchB